# firebase_crashlytics: ^0.2.3 stable version dependencies cannot be added in .yaml. Firebase/CoreOnly showing compatibility issue

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have tried following commands to resolve this issue.

```
flutter clean

pod install
pod update

pod repo update
pod install --repo-update
```

**Every time I received below logs.**

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock):

Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.34.0)

In Podfile:
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 0.5.2, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 6.33.0)

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_core`.
  You should run pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution just need to Delete **Pod folder** + **Podfile.lock** file then just run app it will automatically degrade to what fits well in my case **Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 6.33.0)** as required.